# Facilitate the installation of a Java program which communicates with a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, installation

I am developing a java program which communicates with a MySQL database for a professor at my university.  The MySQL database will be installed on the same computer as the Java program.  I realized the other day that the program's installation is a bit tricky, especially for people not good with computers, so I want to make it as simple as possible for those people.

The current problem is that, for the program to work, a certain user named "sqluser" with password "sqluserpw" must be created in the database and granted all privileges.  Following that, a database with several tables must be created.  I think that creating the database with a JDBC connection wouldn't be so difficult, however, it appears that every JDBC/MySQL example that I see establishes a connection with an already existing username and password which, normally, is created in the MySQL command line.  I don't want people who install this on other computers to need to use the command line, since it is probably a scary experience for them.  Moreover, the person installing it would also have to create the root user as well, THEN grant privileges.

How do I make the installation of this program as easy as humanly possible without switching databases?

Comment: So you need program and MySql db installed on same machine. Right?

Comment: Yes, I need them installed on the same machine.  Let me clarify that in my original question...